# How important is the quality of solutions to NP-hard problems arising in machine learning problems?

Tags: optimization, bayes, optimal-stopping

Machine learning and inference problems give rise to intractable problems. For instance the exact inference in Bayes nets is an [NP-hard problem](https://hips.seas.harvard.edu/blog/2013/01/24/complexity-of-inference-in-bayes-nets/). At the same time there are polynomially tractable classes of Bayesian inference problems [see here](http://coleman.ucsd.edu/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/KMMC-ISIT2013.pdf). In case the problem at hand is intractable, it is very hard to get a good solution as the size of the input increases. However, it should be possible to get a good approximation at the cost of computational time. For large problems though, does it worth the computational effort ?
What is the value of a huge training set if it leads to an intractable inference problem ?

Is it better to go for an optimal solution using smaller training to the expense of potentially skipping crucial parts of your input or to go for worse solutions using a big training set which includes most of the crucial parts.

Comment: I thought most learning problems do scale linearly with number of examples. This is at least the case for the ones I worked on.

Comment: Scaling linearly may be true for some problems but there are definitely NP-hard problems arising when trying to learn patterns.